# JIRA: How to deny permissions for report

Tags: permissions, jira

In JIRA, I want our issues to be visible for all users (Anyone, that is without a login).
I have configured this but all public users are also able to create reports on this issues.
I want to disable this.

How can I deny reporting functionality for the Group Anyone?

Comment: The AbstractReport class that your report extends has a method showReport. This can check for the permission for the user via authenticationContext.getUser()

Comment: Is there no way to do that through the UI ?

Comment: I also want only to disable all existing reports via GUI. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Feedback from Atlassion Support:

From your descriptions, it seems that you had grant Browse Permission on project to Anyone. If you did that, everyone are able to access everything regarding the project including reports for the project.

There are no ways to restrict the report feature. However, it should be able to achieve through customization.

Answer (score 1):

In the [documentation to JIRA](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Managing+Project+Permissions) you find there the list of permissions you may grant or deny. There is no permission to allow creating reports. The reason for that is that anyone that is allowed to view issues, and see a list of issues may export these issues to some other format, so it is a nobrainer to create a report from that.

So I think this is a feature, not a bug, that anyone that is allowed to see an issue may create a report on these issues. What is the business reason you want to deny that?